# Computing UILabel height & UIFont height (for number of lines) using ceil() or roundf()?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have this values that i've logged:

```
label.frame.size.height :18.000000, label.font.lineHeight: 17.895000
```

if i use roundf() like:

```
roundf(label.frame.size.height / label.font.lineHeight) // answer: 1
```

while with ceil()

```
ceil(label.frame.size.height / label.font.lineHeight) // answer: 2
```

but when computed manually: answer is `1.00586756`

I wonder whats the best and more reliable(generally) between this two. Why is everybody using `ceil()` to determine the number of lines of `UILabel`?

Comment: For `1.00586756`, `ceil` gives you `2` while `roundf` gives you `1`. Rounding down gives too small of a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still dont understand why must of the people use `ceil()` when computing the number of line since `roundf()` is more accurate..

But when talking about computing for the number of line.. i look to me that 'roundf()' is indeed more accurate, but since its number of lines.. decimal values are not significant.. [image]

Computing what is the image:

54 / 17.895000 = **3.01760268**

And numberOflines = `3`

if we use `roundf()` answer would be `3` as well

while if `ceil()` is already `4`

therefore using `floor()` or simply converting the result to `int` will do the work:

```
int result = (int)floor(answer);

//or

int result = (int)answer;
```

About my question, i think `roundf()` to the work for me for computing number of lines generally..

I'm making a class that will compute the number of line base  from this values, and will be used by the whole app.

Answer (score 2):

In the case of number of lines each letter after the limit a line could display should be taken to next line so .005 is also significant this .005 part of the text should carry to next line. So it is better to use ceil() rather than roundf( ). In roundf( ) a value will be significant only when it is greater or equal to its half value)

ceil()

> The C library function ceil(x) returns the smallest integer value greater than or equal to x.

Comment: I'm sorry i got confused, isn't it the *width* of the characters/words (depending from what type of `NSLineBreakMode` was used) responsible for carrying the text to the new line? if the word/char exceeds the maxwidth of the label then line breaking is triggered, right?

Comment: even then roundf( ) function is not effective.